# Postgresql - Using multi result sets in another function

Tags: postgresql

I follow this tutorial in order create a function
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure

Here is the code

```
CREATE FUNCTION func1(vtoken character varying, ref1 refcursor, ref2 refcursor)
RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  rec record;
BEGIN
  OPEN ref1 FOR
    SELECT * FROM table1;
  RETURN NEXT ref1;

  OPEN ref2 FOR
    SELECT * FROM table2;
  RETURN NEXT ref2;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I want to create another function and call func1.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION script(vcodebar character varying)
          RETURNS void AS
        $BODY$
        DECLARE     

        BEGIN

            SELECT func1(vtoken,'details', 'amount');
            FETCH ALL IN "details";

        END;$BODY$
          LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
          COST 100;
```

However I receive an error:

> FETCH ALL IN "details";

I can not add BEGIN ... COMMIT before call func1, because it's wrapped in a block BEGIN ... END;

How can I use 2 refcursors from the func1 ?

Comment: Or possible that the cursor are not opened correctly, please show your `issue_ticket` function code!

Comment: I updated my code in the post, because the comment is too short. I run im console psql, it's ok with FETCH ALL IN "details"; But in function it is not

Comment: It seems to be ok, you have to execute the select and the fetch in the same transaction. Can you post de complete thrown error mesage ?

Comment: In the psql consonle, I create Transaction by BEGIN AND COMMIT, then it's ok with FETCH ALL IN "details". However in a function, it's impossible to add more BEGIN. Futhermore, a function is a transaction.

Comment: Could u try with any multi result sets and then call it from another function and display the result ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76738/discussion-between-user1000652-and-houari).

Answer (score 0):

The cursors returned from the function are closed as soon as the call to the function completes. You should wrap the block from the `SELECT` statement until after the last use of the cursors in a transaction block:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT issue_ticket(vtoken, 'details', 'amount');
  FETCH ALL IN "details";
  -- More statements
COMMIT; -- or ROLLBACK
```

Comment: However, I call it from another function, this function has it BEGIN .... END;  Therefore, I can not add another BEGIN  ... COMMIT

Comment: Please edit your question (link at the bottom-left of your question) and add the complete issue_ticket function.